# Finding the default isolation level in SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, concurrency, sql-server-2017, isolation-level

I'm reading a book related to transaction and concurrency. In one paragraph it is mentioned that:

- In on-premises SQL Server instance the default isolation level is Read-Committed based on locking

And the next sentence is:

- The default in SQL Database is Read - committed snapshot based on row-versioning

My question is: what is the difference between "On-premises SQL Server instance" and "SQL Database" in these two sentences?

What is the default isolation level and how can I find it? Is there any special query to find out the default isolation level?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's referring to [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) which uses [RCSI by default](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1639.handling-transactions-in-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx).

> **Isolation Level SQL**
>
> Database default database wide setting is to
> enable read committed snapshot isolation (RCSI) by having both the
> READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION database options
> set to ON, learn more about isolation levels [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189122(v=sql.105)). You cannot
> change the database default isolation level. However, you can control
> the isolation level explicitly on a connection.

In on-premises SQL Server, the default isolation level is Read Committed.

Finding the "default" isolation level is a bit of a goose chase. It will depend on the database where a query is initiated from, and if any hints exist in the query to override a database level setting.

That said, you could query `sys.databases` to find out if RCSI or SI is enabled.

```
SELECT d.name, 
       d.is_read_committed_snapshot_on, 
       d.snapshot_isolation_state
FROM sys.databases AS d;
```

Note that the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is not technically an isolation level. Rather, it is a database option that controls the implementation so that row versioning instead of locking is used to provide read consistency for sessions using the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level.